# Is there a correct way to save document from Javascript Api for Office in Word Desktop client?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

#### Context

I am writing an Office Word Task Pane Addin using JavaScript API for Office (v 1.1).

My system :

- Microsoft Windows 8.1
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Latest Visual Studio Tools for Office
- Microsoft Office Word Service Pack 1 (Desktop)

---

#### Problem

The problem I am facing is about saving the opened document in the client machine. I have searched for information, but remain unsuccessful...

I would like to know if there is a way to save Word document from the JavaScript API, there are only a few methods in the Office.Context.Document :

[image]

---

#### Code

I wrote a solution but I dont like the way I used to save document by creating Word.Application Activex :

```
$scope.saveDocument = function (draft) {
    // Draft is a part of the window title
    // Example : 
    // ----------
    // If word window title shows "B0306-000-2012.docx - Word", 
    // draft could be "B0306-000-2012"
    try {
        var Word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
        if (Word) {
            var spanish = Word.Language == 3082;
            var Tasks = Word.Tasks;
            for (var i = 0; i < Tasks.Count; i++) {
                var Task = Tasks.Item(i + 1);
                if (Task.Visible && Task.Name.indexOf(draft) >= 0) {
                    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    var activated = shell.AppActivate(Task.Name, 2000); //Espera 2 segundos para activar la aplicación
                    shell.SendKeys(spanish ? "^g" : "^s", 3000); //Envía el comando Ctrl + (G / S) según el idioma de la aplicación y espera 3 segundos a que Word guarde el documento
                    break;
                }
            }
            Word.Quit();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        $OfficeApp.showModal("No se pudo guardar el documento", "Error: " + e.message);
        return false;
    }
};
```

---

#### Question

Any suggestion on how to save document using JavaScript API directly?

Answer (score 1):

The Office JS APIs (currently) for Office 2013 have no interface for opening or saving documents.

The only workaround that occurs to me would be to extract the OOXML and "stream" that to a new file (with the file extension xml). But there are certain things the OOXML does not contain (such as document properties) so depending on what content your documents have that might not be an option.

Edit from discussion in Comments:

For anything else, it's necessary to use the old-style VSTO/COM/VBA add-in which offers full object model functionality.

Comment: Do you know @cindy-meister when The Office JS APIs will support saving and / or opening documents? the problem i have is that i need to open the document from Edocs DM extension, so i must save document locally in client machine to allow DM Extension to detect changes... i can do it from Word itself but my Task Pane Addin has a button to Formalize the document, prior to formalize i need to know if document is already saved, then i can formalize it and close inmediately to prevent user make changes post- formalize, am i clear?

Comment: I have no idea about when (or how!) this capability will be introduced.

Comment: I know it was introduced to Api for Word 2016 and Word for iPad :( i am gonna cry :'( please check it out: [Document object (JavaScript API for Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt598679.aspx)

Comment: @user3307754 It looks like it's been added to the JS object model since the last time I looked, although it appears you have no option about setting the file path or name. If you look carefully at the code sample for the save method you'll see there's also a document.saved property that returns whether the document has changes that need to be saved.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but client is Word 2013, there is no way to get 'saved' property :'(, i don´t want to set the file path, i only need to save current document into its original opening path...(such as if i clicked file... save or pressed Ctrl + S) (sorry my bad english, it is not my native language)

Comment: No, with Office 2013 it's not possible, except for the workaround I described. The OOXML is accessible in 2013 as a "coercion type".

Comment: you said: "The OOXML is accessible in 2013 as a "coercion type"", there i can know if document has pending changes?

Comment: No, there's nothing in the OOXML that will tell you that. But then in 2013 your code can't perform an open or a save or "trap" a Save event - your code cannot interact with the document at that level. If you need something like that then you need a VSTO / COM / VBA add-in.

Comment: Yeah, i was researching about web addin by my interesting on change tha actually performing addin (is based on VSTO), i think my client must continue using this old addin, Thanks a lot @cindy-meister, you were a big help for me! will mark as answer ;)

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing for Excel.  Is there a Javascript API for saving the Excel document?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to save is the current document, and as Cindy proposes this is not possible with 2013. It is possible in 2016 plus.

if you want to save a copy of the document (in 2103) you can do it. Note that what Cindy is suggesting is not possible, you can get the entire file in 3 formats: compressed (docx), plain text or PDF, you cannot get the XML unless the user is selecting the entire document.
What you need to do is to use the getFileAsync() method [(here is a sample)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx)   make sure to ask for the compressed format that will give you slices of the docx file, then you can save or upload this file wherever you need to.

Comment: thanks for answering, i need to save document in the same place where document was opened from, Edocs DM extension has a file watcher that detects the change and perform actions with document... don´t know how

Comment: Unfortunately for 2013 that is not possible, I outlined the options and availability for 2016. Thanks!!!!

Comment: This only allows you to upload the document to some remote location correct? Can you actually save the document on a new location? I've only seen the `Document.Save()`, but what if the document haven't been opened from any where? What if it's a completely new document? Can I apply some path and filename to where the file should be saved?

Comment: this API only gets you the document enrypted as base64. once you have that, you will need to write code to save it anywhere you need to.